# Pass function return to JQuery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting a value from a function and trying to pass it as a selector in Jquery. JQUery is not accepting the string that I am passing

```
var make = function() {
  var text = "";
  var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

  return text;
};
var makeimg = function() {
  var text = "";
  var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)

  text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

  return text;

};
var a = make();
var b = makeimg();

var making = '#' + a;
var makingimg = '#' + b;

$("body").append("<div id=" + making + "><img id=" + makingimg + ">     </div>");

alert(makingimg);

//set img to image tag
$(makingimg).attr("src", '/img/someimage.png');
$(makingimg).attr("width", '200px');
```

The alert show the right value and when I run a type of function it is a string but when I pass it as a selector it does not grab the DOM element.

Here is a [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/fipulaxipo/edit?html,js,console,output) with the code.

Comment: Wow, there are a lot of high reps answering this question!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're setting the ID with the hash, so you end up with

```
<div id="#dsadAs"><img id="#dsawqQ"></div>
```

etc. change it to

```
$("body").append("<div id=" + a + "><img id=" + b + ">     </div>");
```

Comment: Thank you. I knew it would be something small. I will mark the answer once the time has passed.

Answer (score 2):

Whilst the other answers deal with the IDs having the extraneous `#` in front, I'd like to offer an alternative method of constructing your HTML where you don't need to look up the element after appending it:

```
var a = make();
var b = makeimg();

//create a new div element
var d = $("div");
//create a new img element
var i = $("img");

//set up attributes on both
d.attr('id', a);
i.attr({
    'id': b,
    'src': '/img/someimage.png',
    'width': '200px'
});

//append the image to the div...
d.append(i);
//...and the div to the body
$("body").append(d);
```

If you were only using the ID's to find the elements to set the `src` and `width` attributes, you don't even need the `a`/`b` variables and `id` attributes now.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because you're assigning the `id` attributes of the elements you create to include the `#`, eg `id="#foo"`, which is incorrect. You need to remove the `#` from those attributes.

Also note that `make()` and `makeimg()` are exactly the same function, so one can be removed. Also, you're setting the `src` on the `div` - this should be on the `img`, and `width` should be an integer. Try this:

```
var make = function() {
    var text = "";
    var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));    
    return text;
};

var a = make();
var b = make();    
$("body").append("<div id=" + a + "><img id=" + b + "></div>");
$('#' + b).attr({
    src: '/img/someimage.png',
    width: 200
});
```

You can also set the attributes when you create the elements and remove the need to query the DOM again:

```
$("body").append('<div id="' + a + '"><img id="' + b + '" src="/img/someimage.png" width="200"></div>');
```

Answer (score 1):

Your elements' ids should not start with `#`. Only the selector should:

```
var divId = make();
var imgId = makeimg();

$("body").append("<div id=" + divId + "><img id=" + imgId + ">     </div>");

//set img to image tag
$( '#' + divId ).attr("src", '/img/someimage.png');
$( '#' + imgId ).attr("width", '200px');
```

Answer (score 1):

When you create the div, you add an id with hash in front. You shouldn't do this, only the jQuery selector get's the hash, see https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/

Instead, do this:

```
var making = a; // remove hash
var makingimg = b; // remove hash

$("body").append("<div id=" + making + "><img id=" + makingimg + ">     </div>"); // ids added without hash

alert(makingimg);

//set img to image tag
$('#'+makingimg).attr("src", '/img/someimage.png');  // add hash to refer to the element
$('#'+makingimg).attr("width", '200px'); // add hash to refer to the element
```